# Retornar formatação original TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Tenho um método, que verifica se um TextBox esta preenchido, caso positivo segue normal, caso esteja em branco, ele exibe uma mensagem na tela, e pinta fundo do TextBox de amarelo, Ai que vem minha duvida, como faço para retornar para a cor padrão?

No momento, para voltar, estou usando:

```
 public void limparCorBoxes(Control.ControlCollection controles)
    {
        //Faz um laço para todos os controles passados no parâmetro
        foreach (Control ctrl in controles)
        {
            //Se o contorle for um TextBox...
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)(ctrl)).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
```

Porém, esse método, me traz problemas, pois tenho alguns TextBox que tem o parâmetro `ReadOnly = true`, que quando utilizado deixa o TextBox com a cor de fundo cinza, e quando executo o método a cima, todos os Textbox ficam com o fundo branco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar mais um teste na sua rotina, para alterar a cor de fundo apenas do `TextBox` que não está com a propriedade `ReadOnly` configurada para **true**.

Veja se funciona:

```
 public void limparCorBoxes(Control.ControlCollection controles)
    {
        //Faz um laço para todos os controles passados no parâmetro
        foreach (Control ctrl in controles)
        {
            //Se o contorle for um TextBox...
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                if (!((TextBox)(ctrl)).ReadOnly) {
                   ((TextBox)(ctrl)).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White; 
                } 

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela resposta, agora uma duvida, pq utiliza o ! na frente do ((TextBox)(ctrl)).ReadOnly) ?

Comment: Desta forma funciona, mais vc também pode utilizar 'System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window' para TextBoxes normais e 'System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control' para TextBoxes  Readonly, pois desta forma se houver alguma alteração de tema do usuário a cor do sistema será utilizada de forma padronizada.

Comment: Thomas, o ! é o operador de negação, o *not* de outras linguagens. Como `ReadOnly` é uma propriedade _boolean_ podemos usar seu valor para testar uma condição de um `if`, por exemplo. Para ficar mais claro poderíamos fazer assim: `if (((TextBox)(ctrl)).ReadOnly!=true)` ou assim `if (((TextBox)(ctrl)).ReadOnly==false)`.

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado. =D

Answer (score 5):

Você também pode utilizar as cores do sistema para melhor padronização:

```
public void limparCorBoxes(Control.ControlCollection controles)
{
    //Faz um laço para todos os controles passados no parâmetro
    foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
    {
        //Se o contorle for um TextBox...
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            ctrl.BackColor = ((TextBox)ctrl).ReadOnly 
                    ? System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control 
                    : System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso mesmo @Julio Borges, o uso das cores do sistema é sempre mais adequada, desde que não seja preciso uma cor específica, pois com as cores do sistema a aplicação vai acompanhar o tema de cores do ambiente em que está sendo executada. +1

Comment: Com certeza, respondi para enriquecer o conteúdo da sua resposta sem editá-la.

Comment: Julio e Emerson, Perfeito. Muito obrigado.. testei aqui e funciona perfeitamente. Obrigado